# Java, PhpBB and creation of new topic

Tags: java, phpbb, http-unit

I need to programmly create topics on my board. I use Java and HtmlUnit for this.
But there is one problem — if program post once all is okay (forum response is http 200), but if start program again then PhpBB response is «http 304» and redirection to category where new topic should be located but topic not added. The question is how to fix this?

Here is WireShark dump of first successfull topic addition (login, posting):
http://a2k.in/2ai

And here is same request but with 304 redirect:
http://a2k.in/2aj

Posting is from admin account with not posting time limitations.
Here is posting from browser (Chrome) log:
http://a2k.in/2ak

What is the problem? The difference between my request and browser request is in header «Cache-Control: max-age=0», «Origin: http://localhost». Maybe there is problem in cache-controller?

Comment: Those links are not helpful. Paste the minimum necessary info in the question.

Comment: Okay! This is http request of browser: http://pastebin.com/pdM09VF5; this is http request of my program: http://pastebin.com/3E3erP2C. When I create thread through browser all is ok. When I create thread through program at once it creates successfully and the next times isn't. After some time it creates successfully again. This is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

maybe a bit late.. but just saw this...

had the same problem when posting more then one thread.

looks like phpbb has some kind of flood protection.

At least for my implementation it helped to simply add a timer /delay between posts... (think i got it set to somewhere around 3 sec. may work with one or two as well not sure... wasnt in a hurry.)